# No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rplidar, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to implement hector slam with rplidar. So far I have no success in launching tutorial.launch in hector slam. I had followed the instructions in this [link](https://hackaday.io/project/7284-oscar-omni-service-cooperative-assistant-robot/log/26164-first-foray-into-ros). Apart from changing the second last line, I have also changed the frame names according to some of the answers in this wiki.

```
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100"/>
```

I'll get this error after running the launch file.

{{{[ WARN] [1457932080.622102713]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.003506 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once.}}}

I tried viewing the tf tree, the output I get is "No TF data received".

Appreciate any help I can get on this issue as I am new to both linux and ROS. I am running ros jade and linux unbuntu. I haven't edit any other launch file from hector slam. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228970/no-transform-between-frames-/map-and-scanmatcher_frame/) by [bongkw](https://answers.ros.org/users/26259/bongkw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [linfeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/26608/linfeng/) on 2016-04-15**:
hello,Have you solved this problem? i am facing this problem the same as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for very late answer.
Have you set the parameter "pub_map_scanmatch_transform" and also set the parameter "tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" as scanmatcher_frame. These parameters must be set for hector_mapping node in order to get a transform between map and scanmatcher_frame. Have a look at the details of this parameters at [link](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping).

---

Originally posted by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) with karma: 166 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1